# Laravel auth user on webhook

Tags: php, laravel, events, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am having trouble with authenticated user in my Laravel/Vue app. Once you log in, you can choose to make a purchase via Stripe which leads you off the page, and returns back upon payment.

Just to make sure, I've made an endpoint:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return Auth::user();
});
```

And before and after Stripe, when I hit it, I do get back the user. So authentication is in order.

What happens though is that Stripe upon payment event makes a webhook callback to my route:

```
Route::post('api/stripe/checkout-session-completed', 'StripeController@checkoutSessionCompleted');
```

Inside a hook, event is fired which should propagate number of credits purchased to the user who made the purchase, however I am always getting that `Auth::user()` is not defined.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
...

public function checkoutSessionCompleted()
{
    ...
    $this->handleCheckout($session); // this is Stripe session object
    ...
}

private function handleCheckout($session)
{
    ...
    event(new PaymentSuccessful($payment, Auth::user()));
    ...
}
```

Was this supposed to happen? How can I get the currently auth user if not like this?

Comment: Did you use multiple guards on your application?

Comment: No. However I did override `EloquentUserProvider` to always return `true` for `validateCredentials` method. But authentication works as expected. It looks as if on webhook POST, new session is made and it doesn't have access to auth user object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like sessions aren't shared when external source makes a POST request to your route. I made a workaround to include user ID within Stripe session metadata, so I can find user by that same ID when request returns via webhook.

```
$stripeSession = Session::create([
    'success_url'          => route('stripe.success') . '/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url'           => route('stripe.cancel'),
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'mode'                 => 'payment',
    'line_items'           => [
        [
            'price_data'  => [
                'currency'    => 'eur',
                'product'     => env('STRIPE_PRODUCT_ID'),
                'unit_amount' => $price->stripe_price * 100,
            ],
            'description' => "Credits to receive: $price->quantity",
            'quantity'    => 1,
        ],
    ],
    'metadata'             => [
        'quantity' => $price->quantity,
        'user_id'  => Auth::user()->id,
    ],
    'customer_email'       => optional(Auth::user())->email ?? null,
    'client_reference_id'  => optional(Auth::user())->id ?? null,
]);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer and to add to it. The POST request for the webhook notification is coming from Stripe's servers. The way that authentication works, it requires the users browser to make requests to your server. You'll want to (1) remove any authentication requirements for the webhook route and (2) either use metadata on the Checkout Session or otherwise store the ID of the Checkout Session in your database and associate it somehow with the user so to look them up when you receive the webhook notification.